# Angular Observer catch error on Component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code on my component

```
  this.authService.login4(this.email, this.password)
         .pipe(first())
         .subscribe(
             data => {
                  console.log(data);

             },
             error => {
                console.log('err');

             });
```

and this implementation on my service :

```
login4(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  return  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api' + '/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  });
}
```

And the err is printed in case of error, but if I change the implementation of login for to this the component err is not printed. Is this normal? I want to know in the component if there is any error.

```
  login4(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

return  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api' + '/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  }).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log(data)),
  catchError(this.handleError<any>(`err`))
);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you catch an error you're stopping it. You could either catch and throw, or not catch until it reaches the component. See two examples below:

#### Catch and throw. Useful for handling *expected* errors.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.login().subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}

login() {
    return ajax.post("http://localhost:3000/api/login").pipe(
        map(data => data),
        catchError(err => {
            throw new Error("My Error");
        })
    );
}
```

#### Don't catch until in component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.login().subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}

login() {
    return ajax.post("http://localhost:3000/api/login").pipe(
        map(data => data)
    );
}
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Its not good idea to suppress the error in Service Class. If you do so you will never be able tell the Component that something went wrong and if the component doesn't know if something is failed. If Component doesn't know it will not throw the error to the end user.

> Eventually End User will be confused if operation was completed or not.

This is one the example however there are several reason to throw the error till Component level.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `throwError` in you catchError

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

login4(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

return  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api' + '/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  }).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log(data)),
  catchError((err) => throwError(err))
);
```